# Is a triple LVL beam adequate for a picture window?

Tags: walls

I want to frame a window opening for a 114" x 47" picture window with right and left casement. The location is the back walkout wall of a 2 story on the main level.

I am wondering if three 1-3/4" x 9-1/2" x 10' LVL beams would be the correct sizing to span all three units.

Comment: yes it will span all units

Comment: Probably depends a _lot_ on what that LVL is supporting above it. Is it on the top floor with a gable end wall above it? It's not carrying _much_ weight. Is it on the bottom floor of a 4 story house in a seismic zone, high winds, heavy snows, and a bathroom tub on each floor above it? It's carrying a _lot_ of weight and that might not be sufficient.

Comment: Assuming this is a new hole in the wall, possible a load bearing wall, the best answer is to have a structural engineer check what you need.  You do not want a two story house become a one story house.

Comment: See [IRC R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7) for header sizes under #2 grade sawn lumber. Using this table we can help you with #2 grade header sizes, but LVLs require an engineer. If you go to an engineer, first thing he'll do is check this table out of laziness. When you cut away a 10 ft patch of wall sheathing, that could impact your house's seismic and wind resistance, so you should at least provide a picture of the wall from outside so that we can at least say "hey, and what about the lateral system?"

Comment: Maximum header height can be an architectural constraint, so you should spec that also if it's important.